# Calling angular bootstrap on an element which has a child element that has been bootstrapped

Tags: angularjs

I'm getting an error when calling angular bootstrap on an element which has a child element that has already been bootstrapped:

```
Unknown provider: myServiceProvider <- myService
```

Here's the call on the child

```
angular.bootstrap($('#child'), ['mod1']);
```

And here's the call on the parent

```
angular.bootstrap($('body'), ['modA', 'modB']);
```

If I include 'mod1' in the bootstrap call on the parent then it seems to work.

Is what I'm trying to do here bad practice?

Comment: You have two nested `<body>` tags in your HTML?

Comment: Oops - have corrected the question. Thanks for spotting that.

Comment: You should also explain why you need two nested angular apps? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Aspx app with a master page that includes different content according to which feature is being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments above the bootstrap function say that apps cannot be nested. [Search 'nested' here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/cb29632a5802e930262919b3db64ca4806c5cfc7/src/Angular.js)

Comment: Thanks Caleb. Must get into the habit of searching the angular source as the documentation in certain areas ain't that hot.